# NSData is empty when i need it in other method

Tags: objective-c, nsdata

I have just created a void for `imagePickerController`, and in its `finishPicking` part I have set an `NSData` that fills with video url, also the `NSData` is set in interface. I need this `NSData` in another void but there I get empty. Any help for that please?

I have tried to set an `NSData` in interface and then `alloc` it in body of `finishPicking` method. Later in another method I tried to reach its value but it is empty.

```
-(void)startMediaBrowserFromViewController:(UIViewController*)controller usingDelegate:(id )delegate 

sharedUrl = [[NSData alloc]init];
sharedUrl = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:theMovie];

-(void)shareIt {

    if(sharedUrl != nil){
        //some codes.
    }
}
```

update

-(void)shareIt {

```
if(sharedUrl != nil){
    NSLog(@"start sharing");
    NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:
                                   sharedUrl, @"video.mov",
                                   @"video/quicktime", @"contentType",
                                   @"Video Test Title", @"title",
                                   @"Video Test Description", @"description",
                                   nil];
    NSLog(@"step1");
    [facebook requestWithGraphPath:@"me/videos"
                         andParams:params
                     andHttpMethod:@"POST"
                       andDelegate:self];
    NSLog(@"step2");
}
else{
    NSLog(@"url is empty");
}
```

}

this is the other void that needs the sharedUrl NSData

Comment: Try `sharedURL = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:theMovie]];`

Comment: thanx for reply .this is my code

Comment: i just update the question

Comment: What is `theMovie`? Is there actually something there?

Comment: yes its a NSUrl grabbed from ImagePicker.

Answer (score 0):

i was using an extern"C" in my code that allocated my UIViewController by itself.

```
extern"C"{
void pushShareLogOut(){
    vr = [[APPViewControllerB alloc]init];
    some code;
}
```

}

that was cleaning all the objects.